# Find $x$ in this equation (in $x^2$)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$
1.097\cdot 10^7 \left( 1 - \frac{1}{x^2}\right) = 8.22·10^{-14}
$$

The answer for $x$ is $2$ but I've tried a couple times and I get $x=1$
Any clue?

Comment: No way $x=2$ or $x=1$ solves this...

Comment: Can you show us how did you got $x=1$? Because after edit , I don't think you meant the same as it is displaying

Comment: I think the comma in the original post, before the edit, was meant to be the decimal separator. (So 1,097 should actually be 1.097 instead of 1097)

Comment: I'm pretty sure 1,097 was supposed to be 1.097 because some countries use , for a decimal point. Also it looked like scientific notation.

Comment: and 1.097 * 3/4 =0.82275 using google  so that would semi work for it but would still be off on the order of magnitude.

Comment: I've restored the decimal separators, using period rather than comma.  The Question is still in bad shape.  At a minimum the OP should explain how they "get $x=1$" to save some guesswork by Readers.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1.097%5Ccdot+10%5E7+%5Cleft(+1+-+%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%5E2%7D%5Cright)+%3D+8.22%C2%B710%5E%7B-14%7D

Comment: @hardmath here's my best guess because they were using scientific notation maybe 2 is the integer part of the value of x  as 2*10^6 fairly close.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee: $2\times 10^6$ is fairly close to what? Certainly not to an $x$ that solves the equation.

Comment: I was thinking of spanning the magnitude difference.

Answer (score 1):

$x=1$ is not a solution, because it makes the left hand side equal to $0$, and the right hand side is not $0$.

$x=2$ is not a solution either, because it makes the left hand side a number $>10^7$, which is definitely bigger than the right hand side.

Actually, the solution is
$$
\frac{1}{x^2}=1-\frac{8.22}{1.097}10^{-21}
$$
so $1/x^2$ differs from $1$ by less than $10^{-20}$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, I overlooked the decimal point when checking the edit. Not that it makes a big difference.

Comment: @amWhy I think everybody is able to conclude that if $1/a=b$, then $a=1/b$.

Comment: Okee dokee.... egreg

Answer (score 1):

Solve
$$1.097\times 10^7 \left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)=8.22\times 10^{-14}$$
which is
$$1-\frac{1}{x^2}=\dfrac{8.22\times 10^{-14}}{1.097\times 10^7 }$$
The RHS is almost zero, but we can write the equation in another way
$$-\frac{1}{x^2}=-1+\dfrac{8.22\times 10^{-14}}{1.097\times 10^7 }$$
that is
$$\frac{1}{x^2}\approx 1-7.5\times 10^{-21}$$
or
$$x^2\approx \frac{4000000000000000000000}{3999999999999999999997}$$
which gives
$$x\approx \pm 20000000000 \sqrt{\frac{10}{3999999999999999999997}}$$
This is actually almost $\pm 1$ but not exactly

I think that the exercise was useful to think about approximated and exact solutions

Hope this helps

Comment: More accurate would be $x^2=\frac{54850000000000000000000}{54849999999999999999589}$. Just kidding ! Cheers :-)